# Reorder numbers in assembly

Tags: string, sorting, assembly, numbers

i was doing a program where you can change number like this.
You input this numbers. 123456789
And the output will be:

```
123456789
234567891
345678912
456789123
567891234
678912345
789123456
891234567
912345678
```

But i cant do it, ill try by taking the numbers as a string and reversing them Like this

```
model small

stack 100
dataseg

  cadena db '123456789','$'

  long_cadena dw $-cadena ;leght string

  cadena_rev db 9 dup(' ') 
  Espacio db 13,10,' ','$'


Codeseg

  start:

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov cx,long_cadena 
    add cx,-2

    lea si,cadena 
    lea di,cadena_rev
    mov di,0
    mov si,9

    add si,long_cadena
    add si,-2
    L1:
       mov al,[di];muevo 
       mov ah,09h
       lea dx,cadena_rev
       int 21h
       mov [si],al
       ;inc si
       ;dec di
       dec si
       inc di
       mov ah,09h
       lea dx,cadena
       int 21h

    loop L1


       mov ah,09h
       lea dx,Espacio
       int 21h

    Exit:
       mov ax,4c00h
       int 21h
end start
```

Comment: That code does things you don't want to do, like watch in debugger what happens when you do `lea di,cadena_rev` `mov di,0` ... then pick just one (which you need). Also you don't need to reverse the string. You need to "rotate" it, i.e. `string_i = original.substring(i) + original.substring(1,i-1)` for `i=[1,9]` and indexing from 1 (and substring(1,0) returns empty string). If you understand this "high level" algorithm, check how strings are compiled in assembler, and what it means to create "substring", adjust for assembly (offsets from 0 are easier), create procedure for that, ...

Comment: and meanwhile keep debugging it all the time, by short pieces of code, to see if it works as expected and the results in registers/memory are correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time answering me, im new at assembly and this is my exam for my assembly class, and well i dont understand very well the algoritm :( any other help?

Comment: each "rotation" would need to do the following: save first element. move 2nd to first, 3rd to 2nd, 4th to 3rd ( 8 times, best done in a loop). then move the saved element to where the 9th was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a loop to display the string, now you need an inner loop to rotate the string one position to the left :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
  cadena db '123456789','$'
  Espacio db 13,10,'$'
.code
  start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov cx,9              ;◄■■ MAIN COUNTER.
    L1:
       mov ah,09h
       lea dx,cadena
       int 21h            ;◄■■ DISPLAY CADENA.

       mov ah,09h
       lea dx,Espacio     ;◄■■ LINE BREAK.
       int 21h

    ;ROTATE LEFT.
          mov bx,8        ;◄■■ INNER LOOP COUNTER.
          lea si,cadena
          mov ah,[si]     ;◄■■ PRESERVE LEFT MOST CHAR.
       L2:
          mov al,[si+1]   ;◄■■ MOVE CURRENT CHAR + 1
          mov [si],al     ;    ONE POSITION TO THE LEFT.
          inc si          ;◄■■ NEXT CHAR.
          dec bx          ;◄■■ DECREASE INNER COUNTER.
          jnz L2          ;◄■■ IF INNER COUNTER IS NOT ZERO.

          mov [si],ah     ;◄■■ LEFT MOST CHAR GOES TO RIGHT.
    loop L1

    Exit:
       mov ax,4c00h
       int 21h
end start
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude! you really help me! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
cadena db "123456789",10,13,"$"

rot: mov si,offset cadena
     mov ah,[si]     ; save first char
     mov cx,8
r1:  mov al,[si+1]   ; move every char 1 position to left
     mov [si],al
     inc si
     loop r1
     mov [si],ah    ; put saved char to end
     ret

start:  mov cx,9       ; 9 times
s1:     push cx

        mov ah,9       ; show current status
        mov dx, offset cadena
        int 21h
        call rot       ; "rotate" it

        pop cx
        loop s1
        mov ax,4c00h   ; return to DOS
        int 21h
```